# Every Material in Viewport is Black, affects EVEE and Material Preview

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I am having this issue in EEVEE and *Materials Preview* where all of my materials are rendering black.

Tried deleting my environment hdri, to deleting all of the lights., seems to be no answer I can find so far.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears that you have the only light in the scene turned off. Click the eye icon next to Light and see if that helps. If not, you may need to increase its power. It just may be too weak to illuminate anything.

Comment: @Electric_Wizard, thank you for your response. My lights are actually compiled within the scene collection, and they have their proper settings to light the scene. However, if I try to increase the lighting it still doesn't work. I've also changed the lighting type as well as deleting them and adding new lights. It's a really weird issue. I've uploaded my file online and shall post a link on the next comment. Thank you again for your quick response!

Comment: link to download file https://gofile.io/?c=zyUkgI

Comment: Don't know why, but in order to make this look correct, I had to disable and re-enable the **ground** collection. This made it render properly in the Eevee viewport for me.

Comment: @Electric_Wizard, same for me. It also worked changing viewport shading strength in some situation (but I don't know how to reproduce it).

Comment: wow that actually worked  it now loads up, thank you for your feedback!